# Find index of element in sublist that is same across all the sublists in a nested list

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have a nested list like this:

```
[[8.0, 16.275953626987484, 5.923962654520423],
   [8.0, 3.0076746636087575, 17.05737063904884]),
  ([8.0, 3.0076746636087575, 17.05737063904884],
   [8.0, -13.268278963378728, 11.133407984528427]),
  ([8.0, -13.268278963378728, 11.133407984528427],
   [8.0, -16.275953626987487, -5.923962654520416]),
  ([8.0, -16.275953626987487, -5.923962654520416],
   [8.0, -3.0076746636087694, -17.057370639048848]),
  ([8.0, -3.0076746636087694, -17.057370639048848],
   [8.0, 13.268278963378716, -11.133407984528437]),
  ([8.0, 13.268278963378716, -11.133407984528437],
   [8.0, 16.275953626987484, 5.923962654520423]]
```

In that list, I want to remove the elements in the sublists that have the same values in the same index, for instance, here I want to remove 8 from all the sublists since its the same across all the sublists at index 0.

How do I do it in a short and simple way without too many hard-coded conditions?

One thing to note here is that the sublists will always have 3 elements while the length of the outer nested list can be anything.

EDIT:
Ill explain my use case here for a much better understanding. Actually the list of lists here represents a figure in a 3d plane, so the sub-lists actually are the coordinates of vertices of the figure in a 3D plane. That's why each sublist will only have 3 items. But the number of sublists can differ for each list. It can be 4(for a rectagle), 6(for a hexagon) and so on.
Even though I have the 3D coordinates, each of these figures/sketches are made on a coordinate plane(or a plane parallel to a coordinate plane at a certain distance) like the xy plane, or the yz plane or the zx plane.
Now since the entire figure is made on a plane parallel to the 3 principal planes, one of the coordinates for each of the vertices will be the exact same, like for a sketch in an YZ plane like in the example, the x coordinate for every vertex is the same.
I just want to find the index of the coordinate that is same across all the sublists here for my use case.

Thank You

Comment: Your list has formatting errors (unmatched parentheses)

Comment: Your list is a list of tuples of lists, but you seem to want to treat both lists in a tuple as individual lists? Or are two indices only the same if they're in the same position in the tuple as well? (in other words, if the odd lines in your example had a `9.0` instead of a `8.0` like the even ones, would you still want them removed?)

Comment: I'm sorry if it is a bit difficult to understand, I'll edit the question and explain it in a better manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems a bit odd, but this is a solution:

```
example = [
  ([8.0, 16.275953626987484, 5.923962654520423],
   [8.0, 3.0076746636087575, 17.05737063904884]),
  ([8.0, 3.0076746636087575, 17.05737063904884],
   [8.0, -13.268278963378728, 11.133407984528427]),
  ([8.0, -13.268278963378728, 11.133407984528427],
   [8.0, -16.275953626987487, -5.923962654520416]),
  ([8.0, -16.275953626987487, -5.923962654520416],
   [8.0, -3.0076746636087694, -17.057370639048848]),
  ([8.0, -3.0076746636087694, -17.057370639048848],
   [8.0, 13.268278963378716, -11.133407984528437]),
  ([8.0, 13.268278963378716, -11.133407984528437],
   [8.0, 16.275953626987484, 5.923962654520423])
]


def unchanging_mask(data):
    def all_inner_iterables(xss):
        if xss and isinstance(xss[0], (list, tuple)):
            for xs in xss:
                yield from all_inner_iterables(xs)
        else:
            yield xss

    return list(map(lambda xs: len(set(xs)) == 1, zip(*all_inner_iterables(data))))


def select_columns(data, mask):
    if data and isinstance(data[0], (list, tuple)):
        return type(data)(select_columns(xs, mask) for xs in data)
    else:
        return type(data)(x for i, x in enumerate(data) if not mask[i])


mask = unchanging_mask(example)
result = select_columns(example, mask)
print(result)
```

It works by determining a mask first, which tells it whether or not a column always has the same value for each element at the deepest level of the nesting.

It then applies that mask to all the values a the deepest level of the the nested structure, preserving type.

It does assume the elements at the deepest level all have the same size.

In response to your change, you say:

```
I just want to find the index of the coordinate that is same across all the sublists here for my use case.
```

In my code, if you do:

```
mask = unchanging_mask(example)
print(mask)
```

You'll find that it provides exactly the answer you're looking for. The result of that is:

```
[True, False, False]
```

So, indicating the x coordinate stays constant, but the y and z do not.

The line after it in my original solution, and the function it uses:

```
result = select_columns(example, mask)
```

... just applies that mask to the original data, preserving structure.

Comment: Thank You for the answer, apologies for the difficult to understand phrasing of my question, I have made some edits in the original question to explain it in a better way.

Comment: @AmanSavaria you indicated you want to preserve structure - my solution does that. And you updated your question to state "I just want to find the index of the coordinate that is same across all the sublists here for my use case." My solution does that as well, I think. If this does not answer your question, can you explain why not?

Comment: Apologies for not accepting the answer...yours indeed is what I needed...thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using list comprehension and flattening of the data.

First, we make sure the list of lists is flattened using a simple recursion

```
DATA = [
    [[8.0, 16.275953626987484, 5.923962654520423]],
    [[8.0, 3.0076746636087575, 17.05737063904884]],
    [[8.0, 3.0076746636087575, 17.05737063904884]],
    [[8.0, -13.268278963378728, 11.133407984528427]],
    [[8.0, -13.268278963378728, 11.133407984528427]],
    [[8.0, -16.275953626987487, -5.923962654520416]],
    [[8.0, -16.275953626987487, -5.923962654520416]],
    [[8.0, -3.0076746636087694, -17.057370639048848]],
    [[8.0, -3.0076746636087694, -17.057370639048848]],
    [[8.0, 13.268278963378716, -11.133407984528437]],
    [[8.0, 13.268278963378716, -11.133407984528437]],
    [[8.0, 16.275953626987484, 5.923962654520423]],
]

def is_last_layer(x: list) -> bool:
    return isinstance(x, list) and len(x) == 3 and all(isinstance(_, (float, int)) for _ in x)


def get_flattened_list(data: list, res: list = None) -> list:
    res = res or []
    for x in data:
        if is_last_layer(x):
            res.append(x)
        else:
            res = get_flattened_list(data=x, res=res)
    return res


FLAT_DATA = get_flattened_list(DATA)
print(FLAT_DATA)
# [
#   [8.0, 16.275953626987484, 5.923962654520423], 
#   [8.0, 3.0076746636087575, 17.05737063904884], 
#   [8.0, 3.0076746636087575, 17.05737063904884], 
#   [8.0, -13.268278963378728, 11.133407984528427], 
#   [8.0, -13.268278963378728, 11.133407984528427], 
#   [8.0, -16.275953626987487, -5.923962654520416], 
#   [8.0, -16.275953626987487, -5.923962654520416], 
#   [8.0, -3.0076746636087694, -17.057370639048848], 
#   [8.0, -3.0076746636087694, -17.057370639048848], 
#   [8.0, 13.268278963378716, -11.133407984528437], 
#   [8.0, 13.268278963378716, -11.133407984528437], 
#   [8.0, 16.275953626987484, 5.923962654520423]
# ]
```

Now, we can use a list comprehension to retrieve the indices to remove

```
index_to_remove = [i for i in range(3) if len({_[i] for _ in FLAT_DATA}) == 1]
print(index_to_remove)
# [0]
```

To now obtain a result with same shape as the original object, one can use a recursion again

```
def get_filtered_data(index_rm: list, data: list = None, res: list = None) -> list:
    res = res or []
    for x in data:
        if is_last_layer(x):
            return [_ for i, _ in enumerate(x) if i not in index_rm]
        else:
            res.append([get_filtered_data(index_rm=index_rm, data=x, res=res)])
    return res


FILTERED_DATA = get_filtered_data(index_rm=index_to_remove, data=DATA)
print(FILTERED_DATA)
# [
#   [[16.275953626987484, 5.923962654520423]], 
#   [[3.0076746636087575, 17.05737063904884]], 
#   [[3.0076746636087575, 17.05737063904884]], 
#   [[-13.268278963378728, 11.133407984528427]], 
#   [[-13.268278963378728, 11.133407984528427]], 
#   [[-16.275953626987487, -5.923962654520416]], 
#   [[-16.275953626987487, -5.923962654520416]], 
#   [[-3.0076746636087694, -17.057370639048848]], 
#   [[-3.0076746636087694, -17.057370639048848]], 
#   [[13.268278963378716, -11.133407984528437]], 
#   [[13.268278963378716, -11.133407984528437]], 
#   [[16.275953626987484, 5.923962654520423]]
# ]
```

Comment: This answer seems to ignore what OP said about the original data being nested (and presumably, them wanting to preserve that nesting)

Comment: @Grismar You're correct, I will revise my approach.

Comment: @Grismar yes I want to preserve the nested format of the original data.